# Реализация интерфейса

Tags: c#

Не могу понять, как решить. Помогите, пожалуйста, начать решать.

> Реализовать класс Expression, который реализует интерфейс IExpression. Наследовать и реализовать от него следующие классы. (Под выражением понимается любой класс, реализующий IExpression).
>
> - Название - Описание
> - Variable - Переменная
> - Number - Число
> - Add - Сумма 2-х выражений*
> - Sub - Разность двух выражений

Пример:

```
Expression e = new Add(new Number(1), new Variable('x'));
Console.WriteLine("");
Expression de = e.diff();
Console.WriteLine(de.Show());
```

Результат:

```
0+1
```

Comment: Документацию почитайте, там всё написано.

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне сказать что конкретно надо сделать, я не понял суть задания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Интерфейсы (Руководство по программированию в C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173156.aspx)

Пример:

```
interface IEquatable<T>
{
    bool Equals(T obj);
}

public class Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Point point)
    {
        return this.X == point.X && this.Y == point.Y;
    }
}
```

P.S. А в задании надо реализовать конкретный интерфейс IExpression.